# Memory allocation for a variable/s in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Hello guys) I would love to get an answer for this question:
Let me share a small portion of code I have written in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int* ptr;
    int var = 7;
    ptr = &var;
    cout << "var address:" << &var << endl;
    int &ref = var;
    cout << "ref address:" << &ref << endl;    
    
    cout << "Var value: " << var << endl;
    cout << "ref value: " << ref << endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

after writing this block of code, I've realized that the addresses that store the variables var and ref are equal. The values these two variables store are the same too. However, I just don't get it in terms of actual numbers of variables the OS memory has allocated for: did the OS allocate memory for ref and var separately or did it allocate only 1 spot in memory for these two(var and ref) variables (if so, does it mean that the spot in memory has two names/identifiers (ref and var)?

I have tried to understand what is actually going on in memory and how does it allocate memory. I wanted to know also how the memory system is actually designed since I cannot comprehend this problem just by drawing box/pointer diagrams.

Comment: A reference is just an alias. It is not a C++ Object (does not need to occupy a location in memory) and any action performed on the reference is performed on the thing it refers to.  So `&ref` is the same as writing `&var`.

Comment: var can only have one address - both ref and ptr refer to that address

Comment: `&ref` means "give me the address of the thing referenced by `ref`" (that is, the address of `var`), not the address of `ref` itself. `ref` may or may not have an address, and even when it does, it's not exposed to the programmer.

Comment: @RichardCritten if the reference is passed to another block of code such as a function, a pointer might need to be allocated to implement it. But the language gives you no way to interact with that pointer, it's hidden.

Comment: @MarkRansom I know but I wasn't sure how much OP needed to know - changed my comment to say _"...does not need to occupy ..."_

Comment: @OP The usage of `&` here: `ptr = &var` is totally unrelated and has nothing to do with the usage here: `int &ref = var;`.  The `&` symbol has two different and distinct meanings.  The first means "address-of", the second is "reference".  Just because both operations use the same syntax doesn't mean one is anywhere related to the other.  I think conflating the two usages of `&` is what may be confusing you.

Comment: In a way you can consider referrences the same as pointers, with one distinction. References cannot be null(ptr) and always (should) refer to a valid object or variable.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Except this question is entirely about another distinction: a reference only sometimes takes any bytes or has an address itself.

Comment: @MooingDuck Fair points, well. the only "memory allocation" is the declaration of the int which reserves memory (most likely on the stack). And both the pointer and reference refer to that.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: the pointer *also* has bytes on the stack, so that is another "memory allocation", but the reference (probably) does not.

Comment: I don't think it's possible using Standard C++ to determine whether a reference is using a _"memory allocation"_ or not.  So I think it's best not to add the additional details unless the question shows an understanding of references already and explicitly asks for implementation details.

Comment: @pep references cannot be reseated - pointers can be

Answer (score 3):

References are not objects and don't have all the basic properties of object such as storage or size. There may be no storage to get an address to. If you try to get the address or size of a reference, you will instead get the address of the referred object or the size of the referred object.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference :

> References are not objects; they do not necessarily occupy storage, although the compiler may allocate storage if it is necessary to implement the desired semantics

So a reference *might* occupy addressable storage, but only when the implementation needs that storage to implement reference semantics (such as by using a pointer in the background). But this is an implementation detail. It is mostly hidden from the developer, and even then trying to get its address will still give a pointer to the referred object instead.

Note that pointers are objects. They occupy storage, have a size and their address can be obtained with `&`, just like an `int`. This is why you observe different behavior with references and with pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, references are glorified pointers, that auto-deference on use, can't be changed to point to a different object after being created, and aren't allowed to be null.

In simple cases like this one, the reference will almost surely be optimized away, and every access to `ref` will be replaced directly with `var`.

But in general case, they occupy storage like pointers, though you can't easily get the address of that storage, because applying `&` to a reference returns the address of the target object.